# Solrj-scala: how to query for a field that may not be there?

Tags: scala, solr, solrj

When we use Solrj in scala, what would be a good way to query for value of a field that may not be present in the document? Getting `Option[Any]` in response would be ideal. If it's a multivalued field, getting empty list would be ideal.

Now I get NullPointerException:

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val solrClientBuilder = new CloudSolrClient.Builder
val client: CloudSolrClient = solrClientBuilder.withZkHost("zookeeper.myhost.net:2181").build()

client.setDefaultCollection("skus")
client.setIdField("sku")

val solrQuery = new SolrQuery()
solrQuery.setQuery(s"sku:13614994")
solrQuery.setFields("inventoryLevel, skuCCs") // skuCCs might not be present in document
val params = new QueryRequest(solrQuery).getParams

val solrDocumentList: List[SolrDocument] = for {
  doc <- client.query(solrAlias, params).getResults.toList
} yield doc.asInstanceOf[SolrDocument]

val inventoryLevel: String = solrDocumentList.map(
  _.getFieldValue("inventoryLevel").toString
).headOption.getOrElse("unknown")

// this throws NullPointerException if there is no such field in document:
val skuCCs: List[String] = for {
  doc <- solrDocumentList
  skuCC <- doc.getFieldValues("skuCCs").toList
} yield skuCC.toString
```

Solr is version 6.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

```
val skuCCs: List[String] = for {
  doc <- solrDocumentList
  name <- doc.getFieldNames
  if name == "skuCCs"
  skuCC <- doc.getFieldValues(name).toList
} yield skuCC.toString
```